# Can I use webassembly for plugins like blender uses python?

Tags: plugins, webassembly

I was talking to a friend of mine who knows a lot about js and wasm.He told me the technology goes far beyond web, since it is basicly a way to run near native applications on devices without actually giving them access to the computer.
Which means that thrid party or untrusted code on a smartphone for instance cannot accidentally or intentional change other apps or parts of the system.
This seamed to me like the perfect conditions to build a plugin system for an application I am working on.
I asked him about it but he was unable to give me a clear answer.
So the question is, can I use webassembly outside of a webbrowser, with custom bindings to safely allow users to extend the functionality of my application (a special image viewer) without sacrificing too much speed? It seams it should work using libnode or something, but is there a problem I might run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how much you know about web assembly but it depends on what your plugins actually should do. If it basically handle Arrays and numeric data with not that match interacting with host applications then it might fit. But when you have heavy object handling then it will not fit at the moment. So for image processing it might be perfect match like it is used in some web examples. Also be aware that some web assembly targeting system or not suitable for none web targets as they generate also some javascript code to be used in browsers beside the generate wasm. Some wasm modules for example require that you call malloc and free for string handling other have functions like new and gc for the nearly the same.